# How do I click a button, retrieve an id, and use that id to do other stuff? - Absolute Beginner to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

An absolute beginner to JavaScript here. It would be great if you could help me figure out the syntax for what I want to do (in order to improve it). It's a simple MCQ. **The correct answer should make the button turn green and otherwise, red.**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

// No idea how to get the id of a button you clicked so everything is hard-coded
document.querySelector('#england').onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector("#england").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
document.querySelector('#spain').onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector("#spain").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
document.querySelector('#italy').onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector("#italy").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
};

});
```

^This is under the `<head> <script></script> </head>` block of code.

```
<h3>Which international football team won the 2020 UEFA European Football Championship (aka Euro 2020)?</h3>
<button id='england'>England</button>
<button id='spain'>Spain</button>
<button id='italy'>Italy</button>
```

^This is under the `<body></body>` block of code.

So how do I:

- Click on any of the buttons and get the id
- Check if the `id = #italy`
  - `document.querySelector(" --insert the id here-- ").style.backgroundColor = 'green';`
- Else, `document.querySelector(" --insert the id here-- ").style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

Why can't I do it?:

- I thought of `var = id of button clicked` and using that variable but I don't know how to do that... How do you write code that knows which button is being clicked?
- Would `document.getElementById()` help? I don't know its application at all.
- I can foresee a scenario where I will have more than 3 buttons and doing things in a similar manner would become very painful.

Please go easy on me!

Comment: A side note on good practices: all JavaScript code which interacts with DOM elements should be placed at the end of the body, right before the closing tag (`<body> ... <script> ... </script></body>`) rather than in the head. In this way you are sure that when the JavaScript code is executed all DOM elements have been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
// Select all buttons `.btnAnswer` and for each one...
document.querySelectorAll('.btnAnswer').forEach(btn => {
  // ... add an event listener for the `click` event that...
  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // ... retrieve the button ID and...
    const btnId = btn.getAttribute('id');
    // ... set the background color to green if thr ID is `italy` or to red otherwise
    btn.style.backgroundColor = btnId === 'italy' ? 'green' : 'red';
  })
});
```

```html
<h3>Which international football team won the 2020 UEFA European Football Championship (aka Euro 2020)?</h3>
<button class="btnAnswer" id='england'>England</button>
<button class="btnAnswer" id='spain'>Spain</button>
<button class="btnAnswer" id='italy'>Italy</button>
```

Anyway the problem with your approach is that the code is not reusable, as it depends on the button ID (which is unique); if you have another question with different options, you will have to write quite a bit of repeated logic.

A maybe preferable approach might be:

```js
const correctAnswers = {
  q1: 'italy',
  q2: 'no',
  q3: 'elizabeth'
};

// Select all questions and for each one...
document.querySelectorAll('.question').forEach(q => {
  // ... fetch the correct answer for the question and...
  const correctAnswer = correctAnswers[q.getAttribute('id')]
  // ... select all the corresponding answer options, then...
  q.querySelectorAll('.btnAnswer').forEach(btn => {
    // ... add an event listener to the `click` event that...
    btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      // ... retrieve the corresponding answer and...
      const givenAnswer = btn.dataset.answer;
      // ... set the background color to green if the answer is correct or to red if it is wrong
      btn.style.backgroundColor = givenAnswer === correctAnswer ? 'green' : 'red';
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="question" id="q1">
  <h3>Which international football team won the 2020 UEFA European Football Championship (aka Euro 2020)?</h3>
  <button class="btnAnswer" data-answer='england'>England</button>
  <button class="btnAnswer" data-answer='spain'>Spain</button>
  <button class="btnAnswer" data-answer='italy'>Italy</button>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q2">
  <h3>Can pinapple go on pizza?</h3>
  <button class="btnAnswer" data-answer='yes'>Yes</button>
  <button class="btnAnswer" data-answer='no'>No</button>
</div>

<div class="question" id="q3">
  <h3>Who is the Queen of England?</h3>
  <button class="btnAnswer" data-answer='elizabeth'>Elizabeth II</button>
  <button class="btnAnswer" data-answer='elsa'>Elsa from Frozen</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the improvements and suggestions. Yeah, I now see where I got it wrong with the logic. Your approach is a definite improvement. Also, wasn't aware of a lot of the syntax you used but after reading the documentation/looking it up, I get it now. Thanks for going beyond to help me out! I will make good use of your techniques. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.id);

}
```

You got it. Remove all `document.qwerySelector()` with this line

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Wasn't quite what I was looking for but I am sure I will use this sometime in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below approach.

- Select all nodes with `document.querySelectorAll('button')`
- Add `onclick` event to all buttons.
- Inside the click event check the target id and apply style accordingly.

  ```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(node => node.onclick = function (event) {
      const nodeId = event.target.id;
      console.log('Clicked', nodeId);
      const bgColor = nodeId === 'italy' ? 'green' : 'red';
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    })
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <h3>Which international football team won the 2020 UEFA European Football Championship (aka Euro 2020)?</h3>
  <button id='england'>England</button>
  <button id='spain'>Spain</button>
  <button id='italy'>Italy</button>
  ```

Comment: @Noob_Coder_1132 you are welcome Please approve my answer f ths helped you.